# Prove $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 \to 0$ in probability.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid with finite mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$

Prove that

$\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 \to 0$ in probability.

I tried to use variance to prove this and also tried to prove using the law of large numbers but I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the random variables $X_i^2$, $i \geq 1$, are independent, identically distributed and have finite mean it follows from the strong law of large numbers that

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \to \mathbb{E}(X_1^2) < \infty \quad \text{a.s.}$$

This implies, in particular,

$$\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \to 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$

**Alternative reasoning to prove convergence in probability:** By Markov's inequality, we have

$$\mathbb{P} \left(\left| \frac{1}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \right| \geq \epsilon \right) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon \, n \, (n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(X_i^2)}_{=\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)=\sigma^2+\mu^2} = \frac{\sigma^2+\mu^2}{\epsilon} \frac{1}{n-1} \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0$$

for any $\epsilon>0$.